# htaaccess password protection

Tags: .htaccess, cloud, cache-control, .htpasswd

i have a development version of a site and so am using password protection. The problem is i am using cloud for managing static contents like images. css, js etc

```
Ste URL : http://www.example.com
Static url: http://cdn.example.org
```

Where cd, is a "A" type entry. When i updated my htaccess for password protection, it is asking multiple times

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/example.com/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Secret Folder"
Require valid-user
```

So how can i remove htpassword for the statc domain(http://cdn.example.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your .htaccess like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^cdn\. CDN

AuthUserFile /var/www/html/example.com/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Secret Folder"
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=CDN
```